# I receive AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', but can't find errors in my "HTML code"

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I keep on receiving this error & have checked the html source code multiple times, as attached below. I'm pretty sure I'm finding the right elements, so the text portion should technically exist.

Context: Building a webscraper; trying to extract the headline. Strangely enough, the code for extracting the summary text & link both work - just not the headline.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
url = "https://www.ribbonfarm.com/"
source = requests.get(url, headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0"}).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

article = soup.find("div")

headline = soup.find("h1", class_ = "entry-title").text
print (headline)
```

Error Message I receive: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 9, in 
headline = soup.find("h1", class_ = "entry-title").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

[HTML Source Code from Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCIRq.png)

Thank you!

Comment: `article = soup.find("div")` ..Which `div`?

Comment: @AbhishekRai hmm... Corey Schafer used a more unique element called "article" (https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/BeautifulSoup/scrape.py), but I wasn't able to find one so I just used div instead. 

The html code for that specific article was 
```` 
div class= "post-7348 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-general series-captains-log entry"

```` 

which didn't feel right putting in, because it was specific to that article, rather than being generalisable to every article on the page. Any advice?

Comment: Something strange was that my scraping of summary text & link still worked. So I don't think that's the main problem, but can't figure what is either.

Comment: what exactly do you want from the page? `MJD 59,143` ..these?

Comment: What result do you get for `soup.find_all("h1", class_ = "entry-title")` (notice I am not using `.text` here, I want to see the actual tags)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Gives nothing. There no `h1` elements on the page . It's `h2`

Comment: Seems so. When I view the webpage in my browser, the HTML I get is different from what is shown in the screenshot. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% clear what you want exactly. This is the way to go..though.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.ribbonfarm.com/"
source = requests.get(url, headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')



article = soup.find("div", class_="hfeed")
title_h2 = article.find_all('div')
for title in title_h2:
    ans = title.find('a')
    print(ans.text)
```

Output:-

```
MJD 59,169
Venkatesh Rao
Captain's Log
Captain's Log
6 Comments
MJD 59,163
Venkatesh Rao
Captain's Log
Captain's Log
1 Comment
MJD 59,151
Venkatesh Rao
Captain's Log
Captain's Log
3 Comments
MJD 59,145
Venkatesh Rao
Captain's Log
Captain's Log
4 Comments
MJD 59,143
Venkatesh Rao
Captain's Log
Captain's Log
5 Comments
Clockmaking: 2
Venkatesh Rao
Clockmaking
Clockmaking
4 Comments
MJD 59,128
Venkatesh Rao
Captain's Log
Captain's Log
2 Comments
Mansionism 2: Bungalows
Venkatesh Rao
Mansionism
Mansionism
6 Comments
Notes: The Marshall Plan by Benn Steil
Venkatesh Rao
Book Notes
Book Notes

2 Comments
Epistemic Reserve Notes
Mike Elias
Wittgenstein’s Revenge,
1 Comment
1
```

Comment: sorry, not sure why my html code was messed up. this definitely helped, thanks!